# Show that the class of the word $aba$ in group $\langle{a,b\,\vert\,a^{2}b^{2} }\rangle$ is not the trivial element.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-presentation

Could anyone give me a suggestion to solve this problem about group presentations?

Show that the class of the word $aba$ in group 
$\langle{a,b\mid a^{2}b^{2} }\rangle$ is not the trivial element.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is a homomorphism from your group to the cyclic group of order 2 which maps the two generators to the nonzero element and aba to a nonzero element.

Answer (score 1):

As a matter of *strategy*, try to find *some* abelian quotient in which $2a + b \ne 0$ (using additive notation).  Note (in your quotient) $2a + b = -b$. So now it suffices to find an abelian quotient in which $b \ne 0$.